# How to use onclick on dropdown without button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make some changes, such as show/hide options or add image source when an option in my dropdown is selected, but couldn’t make the function work somehow … Is there some type of trick to do it without a button?

Related part of code:

```html
<select id="yrank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;">
    <option selected="selected" >Select</option>
    <option onclick="yRankFunc()" value="iron">Iron</option>
    <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
    <option value="silver">Silver</option>
    <option value="gold">Gold</option>
    <option value="platinum">Platinum</option>
    <option value="diamond">Diamond</option>
</select>
    
<script>
    var yRankPic = document.getElementById("yRankPic");
    var nRankPic = document.getElementById("nRankPic");
    var yrankNo = document.getElementById("yRankNo").value;
    var yrank = document.getElementById("yrank").value;
    function yRankFunc(){
        console.log(yrank);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `var yrank = document.getElementById("yrank").value;` Because you read the value when the page renders, it does not keep updating that variable.

Comment: You really should be using onchange of the select, not click events on options

Comment: @epascarello i had tried that before but didnt realize the stupid mistake i did somehow... thanks for reminding the variable part and for your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the value when you want the updated value. You currently read the value when the page renders. You also want to use the change event on the select and in the method, look to see what is selected.

```js
var yrank = document.getElementById("yrank");

function yRankFunc() {
  if (yrank.value === 'bronze') {
    console.log('do something');
  } else {
    console.log(yrank.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="yrank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;" onchange="yRankFunc()">
  <option selected="selected">Select</option>
  <option value="iron">Iron</option>
  <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
  <option value="silver">Silver</option>
  <option value="gold">Gold</option>
  <option value="platinum">Platinum</option>
  <option value="diamond">Diamond</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `change` event listener on select element, and check selected value of target.

```js
const yrank = document.getElementById("yrank");
yrank.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  switch (e.target.value) {
    case "bronze":
      console.log("bronze selected");
      break;
    case "silver":
      console.log("silver selected");
      break;
    case "gold":
      console.log("gold selected");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("others selected");
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="yrank" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-right: 10px;">
 <option selected="selected" >Select</option>
 <option onclick="yRankFunc()" value="iron">Iron</option>
 <option value="bronze">Bronze</option>
 <option value="silver">Silver</option>
 <option value="gold">Gold</option>
 <option value="platinum">Platinum</option>
 <option value="diamond">Diamond</option>
</select>
```